# Do a DoS where you permit only your own connection?

Tags: server, ddos, denial-of-service

Yesterday I was discussing with my brother, a computer scientist, if it is posible to perform a Denial of Service on a webpage so you block all the traffic to the web but you allow your connection to access the web.

This would prove very useful for him as he has an online shop and he's going to apply very large sales and discounts and he considered the option that someone blocked the traffic and get all the products placed there.

Do you think that's feasible? And in case it is, how would you prevent an attacker from doing so?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what a DoS is. Or maybe I didn't understand your text. **To allow** your brother's connection and block everything else, just set the firewall to accept his IP and reject everything else.

Comment: I have seen a lot of websites not taking the technical but the legal roue, adding some statements in the terms of services allowing the seller to cancel a sale if the website encountered technical difficulties at the order time. However, if you go this route I would suggest you to check on [law.se] site first.

Answer (score 4):

This depends a lot on the setup of this site.

If there is no DOS protection at all than it is probably not possible for an attacker to block others from accessing the site while still having access. The attacker might of course try to hack the site and configure a firewall or require authorization so that everyone else gets blocked.

If there is some dumb DOS protection or IDS the attacker might try to create an attack with spoofed source IP in the hope that the IDS or DOS protection will consider these source IP malicious and automatically block them. This way it can be done that only selected IP addresses have access, including the attackers real IP address.